MULTISIG Issue on LOBSTR Wallet
Please help! On 11-22-24 Multi-sig was added to my LOBSTR wallet. I did not add it, I don't have LOBSTR Vault, and I have sent countless tickets to support. I cannot make any transactions and I cannot remove the signers, which are LOBSTR Vault.
I was using my IPHONE to swap out hundreds of tokens that I have purchased over the past few years from the QSI telegram group; I found out they were selling scam tokens.
The response I get when attempting to make transactions is "sent to signature service."
